# What is the letter in red box. How to write it in LATEX?

Tags: letters

What is the letter in red box. How to write it in LATEX? Thank all!
[image: et]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Load `\usepackage{amssymb}` and type `\mathcal{J}`.

Comment: I have tried. It wasn't \mathcal{J}.

Comment: Please edit your post and add a complete but minimal example of your code: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that, then!

Comment: When I type \mathcal{J} in latex, I get similar result to what you want! Also, try \jmath.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

The letter is a calligraphic uppercase "J", likely provided by the Computer Modern (math) font family.

[image]

Various math fonts can render this letter quite differently. I suggest you study pp. 6-8 of the user guide of the `mathalfa` package for several dozen examples of `\mathcal{J}` for various math fonts.

The resolution of the screenshot you posted is not very high. Thus, it will invariably lose detail when compared with the screenshot above, possibly giving rise to the impression that the shapes of the two letters aren't fully identical.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle \mathcal{J}^{-1}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for the basic question, but why use `\displaystyle`? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: @AndréC - The `\displaystyle` directive is there to maximize compatibility with the displayed equation in the OP's screenshot. In the screenshot I posted, the main effect of providing a `\displaystyle` directive is to raise the superscript term (`-1`) by a point or so, relative to what would be the case if a `\displaystyle` directive had not been provided.

Comment: thanks you very much :)